# uiview animation is adding acceleration during animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

I am working on the marquee text in ios using animation like below :

First way:

```
-(void)startScrolling {
      CGRect rect ;
      rect                   =   self.titleView.frame;
      rect.origin.x          =   -self.titleView.frame.size.width;
      self.titleView.frame   =   rect;
      [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
      [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear]; 
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:13];
      [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
      [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startScrolling)];

      // Update end position
      CGRect rect ;
      rect                   =   self.titleView.frame;
      rect.origin.x          =   [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
      self.titleView.frame   =   rect;
      [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

The second way:

```
      [UIView animateWithDuration:13
                            delay:0
                          options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                       animations:^{
                           CGRect rect ;
                           rect                   =   self.titleView.frame;
                           rect.origin.x          =   -self.titleView.frame.size.width;
                          self.titleView.frame    =   rect;

                 }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                          CGRect rect ;
                          rect                   =   self.titleView.frame;
                          rect.origin.x          =   [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
                         self.titleView.frame    =   rect;
                         [self startScrolling];
                 }
 ];
```

The first way is working properly. and the issue for the second way is that acceleration is added during animating. Dont get it

Why acceleration is added while using block. Searching over the internet but I am still getting stuck. Any ideas for this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two code samples you've posted are not equivalent; your setup code should happen before the animation block, and your "end state" code which actually causes the animations should be in the "animations" block. An equivalent block to your first sample would be:

```
       CGRect rect ;
       rect                   =   self.titleView.frame;
       rect.origin.x          =   -self.titleView.frame.size.width;
      self.titleView.frame    =   rect;

      [UIView animateWithDuration:13
                            delay:0
                          options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                       animations:^{
                          CGRect rect ;
                          rect                   =   self.titleView.frame;
                          rect.origin.x          =   [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
                         self.titleView.frame    =   rect;
                 }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self startScrolling];
                 }
 ];
```

Does that help?